# How to parametrize use statement?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

The goal is to execute following tripplet in mysql script and to have single definition of `<schema_name>`:

- `drop schema if exists <schema_name>`
- `create schema <schema_name> default character set utf8`
- `use <schema_name>`

This is followed by a set of `create table` commands inserting tables into **current** schema.

I used user variable `@schema_name` like `set @schema_name = 'database'`. This caused necessity for preparation of the mentioned sql statements:

```
set @drop   = concat('drop schema if exists ', @schema_name);
set @create = concat('create schema ', @schema_name, ' default character set utf8');
set @use    = concat('use ', @schema_name);

prepare st_drop   from @drop;
prepare st_create from @create;
prepare st_use    from @use;

execute st_drop;
execute st_create;
execute st_use;
```

The problem is, that the `use` statement cannot be executed this way:

> Error Code: 1295. This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

Is there any other option how to select the current schema like the `use database` does with the option to pass the `<schema_name>` as the parameter?

Comment: This is usually accomplished via dynamic SQL (aka `execute immediate` in oracle or `exec()` in MSSQL), but MySQL doesn't support it either, though perhaps it [will](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2793) by v6. Is mysql script the only option, could you use some other language to construct these statements as a string and execute it?

Comment: @Timekiller: Yes, only option. The script is relatively long, "hand written" and manually maintained and rewritting it entirely to prepared statements reflecting the `<schema_name>` would be a bit overkill.

Comment: Hmmm... There might still be a way out, how do you execute the said script? Some sort of IDE, mysql source command, mysql < script command?

Comment: Different users use it in different ways (but the goal is to [re]build the database). I've been rather looking for some native alternative, like setup some system variable or so. Looks like there is no simple one.

Comment: I don't think there's a native solution, since MySQL can't work with dynamic SQL. I'm asking because many IDEs support substitution variables - the user is prompted for a value, and the variable is replaced in every line of the script before execution. With mysql command on linux, the same is possible using output/input filtering and pipes.